# Correspond an object's z coordinate to a noise texture?

Tags: animation, procedural

The displacement modifier moves vertices of an object up or down based on how black or white the corresponding part of the texture is.

Is there a way to apply that same principle on multiple separate objects? Is there a way to treat the origin points of each object like a vertex on an object with a displace modifier?

I am trying to animate hundreds of separate cubes in a grid formation to move up and down based on a noise modifier. How could I do this procedurally?

Comment: are all your cubes identical? In that case you can simply use a Paticle > Hair system or Instancing. Please give some details?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the cubes are identical, you can parent a cube to a grid, displace the grid and use the grid as per vertex instancer:

[image]

To do that:

- Create a grid
- Add it the displacement modifier and set its direction to "*Z*"
- Parent a cube to the grid
- In the grid property panel, set *"instancing"* to *"vertices"*.

[image]

If you want some color variation, you can set it using the cube shader. For instance:

[image]

which is done with the object info node on a noise texture:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what I was looking for : )

Comment: Oh that's clever :)